# WordPress - Contacf Form 7 - Как запретить отправку писем по одной почте

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, кто может знает какой плагин, а может снипет/скрипт

Как запретить отправлять сообщение клиенту, который повторно ввел свой адрес эд почты, или номер телефона. То есть что бы проходило проверка, в случае результат повтора почты или телефон, сообщение клиента не отправлялось

Идеально было бы если, сохраненные данные клиенты чистились 1 раз в какой то промежуток, на пример в неделю.

Comment: Что значит "повторно"? Куда, где, какая такая "чистка", какие клиенты в CF7, где код формы? Исправь вопрос, внятно описав что делаешь и что нужно.

Comment: Куки ему поставьте на час, и всё.